# Trouble Making a Matlab Depth Profile Plot (3+ x-variables vs. same y-axis)

Tags: matlab, plot, x-axis

I'm trying to make a depth profile plot ([example](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dharmamony_Vijai/publication/318866687/figure/fig7/AS:614345826385927@1523482867855/Vertical-profiles-of-temperature-C-salinity-PSU-and-density-s-th-at-two.png)) that has 3 x-variables plotted against the same y-axis (depth). Default matlab, as I understand it, is only able to plot 2 variables ([matlab example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/graph-with-multiple-x-axes-and-y-axes.html)). I've checked the file exchange and have tried to use [addaxis](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9016-addaxis) and [axis xx](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47846-axis-xx), but I can't find a relevant example to work through their code; and it seems there have been some bugs due to matlab updates, such that I can't even reproduce the provided examples.

Quite simply, does anyone know how to do this in matlab and/or could link a relevant example? I've seen plenty of ways to make 3+ y-axes, but I can't seem to find one for 3+ x-axes.